# Can IE preserve backslashes in CSS content property's value returned by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, pseudo-element

Considering the following JavaScript, CSS, and HTML codes:

```js
console.log(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('p'), '::before').getPropertyValue('content'));
```

```css
p::before {
    content: "Apparently we \" \" had " attr(data-test) " \" a \" great \" height \"in\" the atmosphere";
}
```

```html
<p data-test="reached"></p>
```

I'm trying to get CSS content property's value via JavaScript and insert it into the DOM.

The value might contain one or more quotation marks with backslashes before them for escaping purpose, like the example above illustrated.

On Firefox, the returned value, including the attr(data-test), are all easy to parse and convert because the backslashes before quotation marks are preserved:

```
"Apparently we \" \" had " attr(data-test) " \" a \" great \" height \"in\" the atmosphere"
```

Chrome goes a step further and converts the attr(data-test) before returning the value, and that is also good:

```
"Apparently we \" \" had reached \" a \" great \" height \"in\" the atmosphere"
```

But on IE11, the backslashes are all gone in the returned value, and that seems to make it impossible to recognize which quotation marks are for wrapping strings and which ones are part of strings:

```
"Apparently we " " had " attr(data-test) " " a " great " height "in" the atmosphere"
```

Is it possible to make IE preserve those backslashes so that the returned value can be parsed and converted?

Comment: I made several tests to get the desire result. Based on my testing results, I found that it is not possible to get the desire result with exact above content. For a work around, You can try to use single quotes with double back slash in your content can help you to get similar kind of results. So if you are available to use the work around than it may help to solve your issue with IE. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thank you. Yeah, it looks like writing extra backslashes for IE is the fastest solution.

Comment: I had already submit a feedback regarding this issue to Microsoft developers. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thank you. But isn't the support for IE has discontinued?

Comment: Yes, I had also tested this issue in MS Edge and got similar results. So I provided a feedback for it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I see. Thanks!